# Show that Banach space valued function is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, separable-spaces

I am given a seperable Banach space and an interval $J$. Pettis' theorem tells that for such a space $Y$, we have: $f : J \rightarrow Y$ is measurable iff for any bounded linear functional $g \in Y^*$, the real function $J \ni t \mapsto g(f(t))$ is measurable.

Now I am supposed to use this theorem to show that any function $f \in C([0,1],Y)$ with a separable Banach space $Y$ is measurable.

**My confusion**: Given such a continuous $f$, and noting that we have the Borel sigma algebras on the interval $[0,1]$ and $Y$. Is such a continuous map not automatically continuous, since the preimage of open maps is open ($f$ is continuous) and the open maps generate the Borel sigma algebra?

Do I miss something or does this indeed follow automatically by continuity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have mis-understoood Pettis Theorem. It says that $f$ is measurable in the sense it is the limit of  sequence of simple functions. (There are several notions of measurability for Banach valued functions).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Would it then be enough to see that $g \circ f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous real-valued function for every $g \in Y^*$ and conclude that this continuous function must be Borel measurable. Hence, $f$ must be measurable by Pettis' theorem?

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help!